# Entity Framework 7 and EDMX manipulation to auto-generate custom code

Tags: entity-framework, t4

I currently use EF6 and use the model first approach. As I understand it, EF7 will be moving away from using an EDMX, and going from a more code-first approach. Now I know I will still be able to reverse engineer from my database into classes if need be.

However one thing I am not sure about is any manipulation I currently do with EF6 will be supported in anyway in EF7.

At the moment, I write T4 templates that read through the EDMX, pick up on the entities, and create new classes based on them. For example, I create partial classes for each entity that has deep clone methods in them. I also create repository classes based on the entities and create methods for finding by primary key, based on which properties in each class have been identified as the primary key.

If I lose the EDMX, does this mean I need to go back to manually creating these? Or is there another way?

Comment: I am having hard time to port even small piece of code to EF7 now.

I wish someone in MS will make the EDMX open source.

Because those DBAs in corporate world will NOT agreed to code first approach. At least not in foreseeable future!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using T4 templates, you can switch to something like CodeFirst -> ReverseEngeneer approach.

You update model in code, generate new migration, test it on a database and then use a reverse engeneer code first approach (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/data/jj593170.aspx) to generate everything else. Theoretically it can be automated.

In my team we do it manually, but we do not need migrations, only a code first contexts and a lot of additional things, that T4 generates whery well.

Comment: So basically the t4 templates would be manipulating the database rather than the EDMX?

Comment: Still EDMX, but it won't be stored anywhere. ReverseEngeneer tool creates it on the fly.

Comment: I'll need to give that a go. How does that work with changes I normally make to the EDMX? Namely for changing the Id column of certain tables into an enum column.

Comment: @eyeballpaul have u done any work on this? I was about to ask same question. Any updates on how to generate the code in case of EF7 without edmx file?

Comment: @Riapp no sorry, I have put EF7 on the backburner until it is more feature complete, along with asp.net 5.

Comment: @eyeballpaul I made same decision to put is aside. The EF7 is pretty raw in current beta version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still use T4 templates with Code First, We navigate Entity Classes instead of the EDMX Model, .

I have been looking at VS2015 recently and having some issues with T4 and asp.net 5 and related projects (FileManager hangs for multiple file outputs and you will need the latest version of Visual Studio, currently Update 1)